Space Vector Modulation vs SInusoidal Carrier Based PWM
I wanted to clarify the difference between these two as I think I realized I had a misunderstanding of what each of these schemes incorporated.
In a sinusoidal based PWM you have a reference signal (with a fundamental frequency) and compare it to a triangle wave of a given sampling frequency with a comparator. The output are the gating signals for whatever you are controlling.
In SVM, you feed reference signals into the modulation scheme where the reference signals for a 3 phase system are transformed into an alpha and beta signal which is used to compose a reference vector including information on dwell times for each switching state. The SVM scheme then outputs what exactly? I was always under the impression switching patterns were output typically via this reference signal directly but I see what looks like this being output when I look around online. 
I assume this is just a new modulation reference based on SVM and needs to still be converted to gate pulsed via PWM? I thought there would be gating signals being composed by SVM as is in the case of sinusoidal carrier based PWM.
I guess my disconnect here is that I originally thought both modulation schemes inherently included the conversion to gating signals but each modulation scheme is actually just referencing what is being used as a reference wave to input to a gating signal generator?
For some context, I was playing around on a few simulation programs and it seems like some have SVM blocks that only output the attached signals and then some seem to have "pwm" included like in the matlab simulink block that actually output gating signals?
Further clarification:

I'm wondering if im hung up on semantics by looking at this picture. the SPWM and THIPWM are pointing to JUST the reference signal. No PWM has taken place yet in any of the colored signals, they are just reference waveforms. I do not understand why PWM is in their names if you STILL need to convert these signals with PWM to useable gating signals with the black carrier wave.


I assume this is just a new modulation reference based on SVM and
needs to still be converted to gate pulsed via PWM? I thought there
would be gating signals being composed by SVM as is in the case of
sinusoidal carrier based PWM.

You are correct, SVPWM generates those gate signals - it's part of SVPWM.

I do not understand why PWM is in their names if you STILL need to
convert these signals with PWM to useable gating signals with the
black carrier wave.

Their goals: SVPWM & THIPWM can work for a symmetrical system only, the output phase voltage can reach higher voltage as rectified input voltage, which is useful for electric drives - you supply an inverter with 400VAC and you output 15% higher voltage. Of course at a price - symmetric load with floating star point.
PWM delivers sine output, its output amplitude is lower than input due to diode and transistor drop voltage. Can supply unbalanced load.
